# Trying to turn off auto suspend on wireless receiver

Tags: wireless, usb

Hello I am trying to turn off the auto-suspend on my wireless receiver, but I do not know the location of the receiver's folder.

Here is the output of `lshw -c network`:

```
PCI (sysfs)  
 SCSI                      
 *-network        
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
   logical name: p3p1
   version: 07
```

Comment: resources: irq:42 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:f1404000-f1404fff memory:f1400000-f1403fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@3:1
       logical name: wlan0

Comment: What is "auto-suspend"? What are you trying to do?